# A more efficient way to find percentage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From a dataframe after using groupby want to identify the success/unsuccessful 
rate. With my limited knowledge in Python and pandas though I made it, but looks inefficient and clumsy. There must be some simpler and efficient way. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
BldgID  BldHt   Device  Date      Time     Result
1213    35      758     20181120  105550   OK
1213    35      758     20181120  105540   NG
1112    40      780     20181120  003102   OK
1117    26      790     20181120  002557   OK
1111    65      780     20181120  002102   NG
1214    80      758     20181120  001600   OK
2902    34      780     20181119  005410   OK
1232    90      780     20181119  001410   OK
1222    75      760     20181119  010552   OK
1214    80      758     20181119  010052   OK
1214    80      758     20181119  005553   NG
1246    16      790     20181119  004556   OK
1128    15      758     20181119  004552   OK
1128    15      758     20181119  004552   OK
1211    30      790     20181119  003557   NG
1211    30      790     20181119  003558   OK
```

Here is the dataframe (csv). At first I want to group the [BldgID, BldHt, 
Device] and find their percentage of Result, i.e. OK/OK+NG. What I did 
was, change 'OK' to '1' and 'NG' to '0'. Sum all the 'OK'. To find the 
total number (OK+NG), I used the dataframe before changing their value (1 
& 0) and calculated the total num. Otherwise, it did not count the NGThen 
dividing them to find the percentage of 'OK'.

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df1 = df.groupby(['BldgID','Device'])['Result'].agg('sum').reset_index()
df1 = df.replace({'OK':1, 'NG': 0})
df1 = df1.groupby(['BldgID','Device'])['Result'].agg('sum').reset_index()
df1['NumOKs'] = df1['Result']

# used the original df i.e. change OK=1, NG=0, to count the total num of
# OK+NG
df2 = df.groupby(['BldgID','Device']) 
         ['Result'].agg('count').reset_index()

df2['sum'] = mel_df2['Result']
df2.drop(['Result'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df3 = pd.concat([df1['NumOKs'], df2['sum']], axis=1, keys= 
['NumOKs','sum'])

df3.head(10)
# sum represents OK+NG
       NumOKs     sum
 0       2        2
 1       6        6
 2       2        2
 3       2        2
 4       2        2
 5       3        4
 6       3        3
 7       3        3
 8       2        3
 9       3        3
```

I got what I wanted but it looks very ugly and inefficient. But with my 
limited knowledge I have to find something quick and it works. Want to 
achieve this in a better and simpler way.
note: The result may not be exactly reproduced as I cut-paste a small 
part of code and result to explain what I want and how (badly) I did it.

Comment: You can use mean to calcuate percentages.... `df.groupby(['BldgID', 'Device'])['Result'].apply(lambda x : (x=='OK').mean())`  Does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, try using `mean` and boolean condition:

```
df.groupby(['BldgID', 'Device'])['Result'].apply(lambda x : (x=='OK').mean())
```

To add this to your dataframe:

```
df['mean_ok'] = df.groupby(['BldgID', 'Device'])['Result']\
                  .apply(lambda x : (x=='OK').mean())
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Tried on a small part and seems working fine.

Comment: How to put name to this newly generated column (4) with mean value, to                                    access this attribute like others?

Comment: Thank you. I actually tried the exact same way. But not working. If I try with the same df name, then it is giving following TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
                    If I make a new df, say df1 = df.groupby(['BldgID', 'Device'])['Result'].apply(lambda x : (x=='OK').mean())     then it is not giving error, but df1.head(10) showing no new column name.

Comment: Adding new column is solved! Just to add reset_index() at the end. That is, df['mean_ok'] = df.groupby(['BldgID', 'Device'])['Result']\
                  .apply(lambda x : (x=='OK').mean()).reset_index()